# Is Unity's dash supposed to go away when I click outside of it?

Tags: unity, unity-dash

When opening the dash with my super key and then deciding that I do not need the dash after all, I can dismiss it either by pressing the super key again or by hitting escape. The first thing that comes to my mind though is to click outside of the dash, but that does not do enything. Is that intended behaviour?

UPDATE: this has been spurred by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/798642

Comment: I think that when clicking outside of the Dash that it should close, I have tried it and it works on my PC.  Hopefully someone will be able to give you a full answer.

Comment: I am in agreement with @scouser73.  Mouse clicking outside of the dash area closes the dash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is supposed to close, but it seems it first needs to fully show, so you might need to wait a bit before closing it works (but that's also true for the <kbd>Super</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> key).

Comment: Ha. I tried different user and found out it works. Then I find out it works only if shortcuts are rolled out. If I roll in shortcuts (by clicking on the little arow pointing down next to the text "shortcuts" - the shortcuts then fold in and the arrow starts pointing right), it stops working when I click the area where shortcuts were displayed. If I click beside that area, it starts working. Can you confirm this? I would report a bug then.

Comment: FYI - It also doesn't close if the area you are clicking in is on a different monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it closes the dash, but as **htorque** stated, it needs to fully show first, and make sure you don't click it too close to the bottom of the dash.

I don't know why it works that way. In my case, clicking on the right side of the dash, although it is very close from the dash, works. However, I need to take some small space from the bottom of the dash to make it work. Maybe it is a bug, or there is some invisible (transparent) part of the dash in that position.